# GlusterFS Mount

Tags: mount, filesystem, mountpoint

I am using glusterfs version 9.2 and seem to be having the issue where a mounted glusterfs volume randomly unmounts. I have done some googling and it seems where a couple others have had the same issue and it seems the general advice was to update glusterfs due to bugs, however that was for older versions and I am using version 9.2 as stated. Can anyone kindly help or advice me on this issue?

Comment: There should be some information in `/var/log/syslog` from the time the volume disconnected. From experience with other 9.x versions, though, this can happen if your network connection is interrupted. Your logs should have something better than a guess, though ... 

Comment: Yeah thanks. There isn't much in syslog and looking at the glustermount log I cannot seem to see what is wrong either. The only workaround I can seem to use at the moment is monit to detect the path is unmounted and remount it.